# How to make my text box with 25% width and image with 75% width the same height?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using standard bootstrap 3 but can't make an image and a text with a background color scale nicely together as a block. Any clues ?

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-3">Lorem ipsim novarum.</div>
   <div class="col-xs-9 img-responsive"><img src="img/landscape.jpg" alt="sibe"></div>
</div>*
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the 'img-responsive' class on the image itself e.g:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">Lorem ipsim novarum.</div>
    <div class="col-xs-9"><img src="img/landscape.jpg" alt="sibe" class="img-responsive"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Since you already answered, here's the doc link i was going to post for reference ,
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images

Comment: Thanks for correcting my typing mistake. My actual code with slideshow has the class on the image,  but I messed up making the code simpler for here.

Answer (score 0):

Make row your actual container. This way when the image height scales, the 'row' div will wrap it nicely. This means give row the background color. and float the image left, with a right margin.